# How to get identical colors for categories between different plots in Dimple

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have two plots displaying different aspects of the same data. Both have the same attribute last in the array:

```
chart_scatter.addSeries(["time", "valueA", "valueB", "category"], dimple.plot.bubble);
chart_scatter2.addSeries(["time", "valueB", "valueA", "category"], dimple.plot.bubble);
```

You can find an image in the comment, I am not allowed to post inline images yet.

I would like the points to be colored the same in both charts. If Category is 1364 it should be say green in the first plot and also green in the second plot. How can I achieve that? Using an interpolated ColorAxis is not an option as those colors are not looking good and would imply order while the data is categorical.

Comment: This gives me for example this: http://i.imgur.com/s1v8F9c.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the assignments like this:

```
chart_scatter.draw();
chart_scatter2._assignedColors = chart_scatter._assignedColors;
chart_scatter2.draw();
```